# Does create-ami command support sshkey of EBS backed instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-ami

AMI is provided by AWS

In the below command, we are creating an ec2 instance using `SOME_OLD_AMI`:

`export EC2_INSTANCE_ID=$(aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ${SOME_OLD_AMI} --key-name ${SOMEKEY}`

and then stopping it:

`aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids ${EC2_INSTANCE_ID} --region ${REGION}`

---

Now, we are customizing an ami with this stopped instance:

```
       aws ec2 create-image --instance-id ${EC2_INSTANCE_ID} --name ${SOME_NEW_AMI} --description "xyz"
```

---

Can we ssh EC2 instance(launched using `SOME_NEW_AMI`) using private  key(`SOMEKEY`)? because ssh key was assigned to `EC2_INSTANCE_ID`....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

If the AMI is provided by AWS, then there is some software installed on the instance that will take the key nominated during `RunInstances()` and will add it to the `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. This then allows you to login using the private half of the keypair.

If an AMI is taken of this instance, then the keypair will remain in the `authorized_keys` file.

Next, if a new instance is launched with that AMI, another keypair can be passed via `RunInstances()`, but the old keypair will still be there and can be used.

So:

- **Instance 1 launched with Keypair 1:** Can connect using `Keypair 1`
- AMI created from Instance 1
- **Instance 2 launched from AMI, specifying Keypair 2:** Can connect using *either* `Keypair 1` or `Keypair 2`

Comment: It comes by specifying a Keypair when an instance is launched from the AMI. You are not required to specify a keypair when launching an instance. If no keypair is specified when launching an instance from the AMI, then only `Keypair 1` can be used to connect.